# php simplexml adding children-nodes in a loop

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm having a trouble with SimpleXML and addChild().

I am trying to generate an order-file in XML from data in a mysql database. 
I want the file to be formed like so:

```
<Ordreimport> 
 <Kunde> 
  <..>
  <Orderline>
    <data>
  </orderline>
  <orderline>
   <data>
  </orderline>
 </kunde>
</ordreimport>
```

The problem is that the following code

```
    $OrderXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><OrdreImport></OrdreImport>');
While ($kunderad = mysql_fetch_array($HentKunde)) {

    $OrderXML->addChild('Kunde');
    $KundeInfo = $OrderXML->Kunde->addChild('KundeID',''); //BD60 - Kundekort - Kundenr
    $OrdreHode = $OrderXML->Kunde->addChild('OrdreHode'); //OF14 - Ordrehode
    $OrdreHode= $OrderXML->Kunde->OrdreHode->addChild('OrdreLinje');

    while ($olrader = mysql_fetch_array($HentOrdrelinje)) {         
        $OrdreLinje = $OrderXML->Kunde->OrdreHode->OrdreLinje->addChild('StatusHB'); //se over.
    }   

    Header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo $OrderXML->asXML();
```

Gives the following result:

```
<Ordreimport> 
 <Kunde> 
  <..>
  <Orderline>
    <data>
    <data>
  </orderline>
 </kunde>
</ordreimport>
```

Also having `$OrdreHode= $OrderXML->Kunde->OrdreHode->addChild('OrdreLinje');` inside the loop, like I initually though, gives the same result, except that it also creates an empty `<orderline>` tag for each additional orderline in the database. Which is ALMOST correct, except all the data ends up in the first `<orderline>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the entire XML tree for adding nodes. So the first one will be selected. Use the current generated node instead.

Further more write headers and the XML outside the loop.

```
while ($kunderad = mysql_fetch_array($HentKunde))
{
  $Kunde      = $OrderXML->addChild('Kunde');
  $KundeInfo  = $Kunde->addChild('KundeID', ''); //BD60 - Kundekort - Kundenr
  $OrdreHode  = $Kunde->addChild('OrdreHode'); //OF14 - Ordrehode
  $OrdreLinje = $OrdreHode->addChild('OrdreLinje');

  // execute statement to query related data rows here

  while ($olrader = mysql_fetch_array($HentOrdrelinje))
  {
    $OrdreLinje = $OrdreLinje->addChild('StatusHB'); //se over.
  }
}

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $OrderXML->asXML();
```

Note that `mysql_` functions are unsafe and obsolete in newer PHP versions. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

You do not show how you query the results of the line:

```
while ($olrader = mysql_fetch_array($HentOrdrelinje))
```

Without executing the statement related to the current `$kunderad` within each iteration of the outer loop the inner loop won't query any new datasets. I assume you actually did and cutted this out from the minimal example.

Comment: Thank you. So obvious when I'm presented with the solution.. :)
You are correct. I tried to post minimal data for clarity. 

I'm adapting some old code, and will ofcourse update to mysqli etc. :)